# How to turn off stripe for a nested table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for my project.

A table has another nested table in its cells. The outer table has table-striped class and it's inherited to the inner table. Is there an easy way to stop the inheritance for the inner table so that only the outer table is striped?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: What are the properties you don't want on the inner table that are on the outer one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.table-striped table {
 /* Undo any styles from the table-striped class here */
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what goes inside the brackets?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552013/4126114) combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075794/bootstrap-table-without-stripe-borders#comment34903273_18076022) seem to work

Comment: Try a class like -- .table-not-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background-color: transparent!important;
        }

Answer (score 5):

Create your own class, like this, and add it to your table:

```
.table-not-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
background-color: transparent!important;}
```

Be sure to use the !important flag.  Can't take credit for this answer-- saw it on CodePly. However, I did add the !important flag.  Without it, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can override styles for inner table:

```
table > table {
/* inner table styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-unstriped  > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-unstriped > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td {
 background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!