# Bootstrap forcing table striping

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a table inside of a table.  On the outer table I want striping and borders, but on the inner one I don't.  I did this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <table class="table table-sm table-borderless" style="margin: 0">
```

Both the outer *and* inner tables have striping.  How can I force that inner table to not have stripes or borders?

Comment: can you share the full code here please

Comment: do you know how to check the definition of any class like "table-striped" in css on internet i probably tried many a things could not get it right though i removed border from internal table

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#examples)...

> "**All table styles are inherited in Bootstrap 4**, meaning any nested
>   tables will be styled in the same manner as the parent."

So in order to override the stripes on the nested table you'd have to add a little CSS...

```
.table-nostriped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:transparent;
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-sm table-borderless table-nostriped">
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/95b4ecfFP7

Comment: i tried it with opacity didnt worked can you say  me if we can watch the bootstrap css' classes deinitionsomewhere?

Comment: definition in mean

Comment: @ZimSystem That does make the striping away, but seems to force the background to white for some reason.  The parent table row is that light-grey, for example, but then this `td` element is all white.

Comment: This solution, in combination with dropping the "table" class from the nested table did it for me (as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075794/bootstrap-table-without-stripe-borders#comment34903273_18076022))